# Invalid Reset Password Token ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, token, reset-password

I generate a reset password token in one request, but then when I want to reset the password in the next request, it says invalid token.

```
public async Task<string> GetResetToken(string userId)
{
    var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(userId);
    return token;
}

public async Task<IdentityResult> ResetPassword(string userId, string token, string newPassword)
{
    var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(userId, token, newPassword);
    return result;
}
```

These two functions are called by their respective API endpoints. The flow of the whole process is:

1. Enter email on website
2. The API generates a token and an email gets sent with a reset link
3. The reset link takes you to a reset password page
4. The page hits the API again to reset the password

Everything works except step 4, because the API just comes back with invalid token. 
I've checked that the token being generated is exactly the same as the token received in step 4.

Comment: How is the `_userManager` initialized?

Comment: Ah thanks for the tip, when I went to look at the _userManger I saw someone set the tokens to expire almost immediately